# DecimalFormat is returning -0.00

Tags: java, decimalformat

This bit of code

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
return formatter.format(-0.001);
```

returns

"-0.00"

I would really prefer (and expect) "0.00"

I know I can fix this by writing a subclass of DecimalFormat, but is there a way to do this using the standard DecimalFormat?

EDIT: I only wan't to change the particular case where the result is "-0.00". All other negative values should remain unchanged, eg: -9.1 -> "-9.10"

Comment: Are you saying you want to always return the absolute version of the number? Or only in the case of `-0.00`?

Comment: Only in the -0.00 case. I still expect, for example, -9.01 -> "-9.01" and 56.001 -> "56.00"

Comment: Blame [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), `-0` is `0` with the negative bit set. See also [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

Answer (score 0):

You could test the string when it's returned.

I don't believe formatting will manipulate the value.
It can only format it. Perhaps you can round it first, and then format it?

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
double x = -0.001;
double y = Math.round(x*100.0)/100.0;
return formatter.format(y);
```

Comment: If I have to add those 2 lines everywhere I use the DecimalFormatter it would be better to create a sub-class and override the format method as I alluded to in the question.